# users acces database and table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I look at databases,table and column for individual users?

Answer (score 1):

User below query:
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`USER_PRIVILEGES`

Comment: no , database dont show

Comment: I want to show
all users which database permission

Comment: Please check query updated.